# is it safe to compress the File History folder?

Tags: windows, compression, file-history

Is it safe to compress the File History folder in Windows 8?  Mine has grown rather big and a lot of the files types would compress well.  However, I dont see any information on compressing it.

It looks like it should be safe, but Id rather be safe than sorry later.

Comment: What all considerations do you have to call it safe? What concerns do you specifically have, to consider it safe or un-safe?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you go this route:

[image: NTFS Compression Dialog]

No problem at all, perfectly safe. You might find it's a bit slower.

Incidentally, files like JPG, MP3, MP4, WMV, AVI, etc. do not compress (or only very little) so if your File History is full of those, you won't see much improvement.

**EDIT:** NTFS compression works at the file-system level. It's as safe to use as NTFS is safe to use as a file-system. That's because NTFS compression is an *integral part of the NTFS functionality set*.

File History is not some kind of sector-based disk tool, it's just a service that copies files and maintains version history. The target destination for File History can even be a network location! This is more that enough evidence that you can safely specify a target folder that has NTFS compression enabled.

Comment: Sorry about the Win7 screen-shot, Windows 8.x will look slightly different but function exactly the same.

Comment: Useful reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#File_compression

Comment: This doesnt answer the question.  Its not a question of can I, but *should* I.  You say its safe, but no reason why.  Haven you done it?  Has someone else done it and documented it?

Comment: @Keltari NTFS compression works at the file-system level so it's *transparent* to File History as it is transparent to everything else. If NTFS compression were to cause issues for File History, then that would mean NTFS is fundamentally broken and other applications/services would be affected too. That is certainly not the case. More reading: http://tinyurl.com/mm4of69

Comment: sigh, you arent getting the question.  Yes you *can* compress everything, but it doesnt mean you should.  If the File History gets written or read to a lot, de/compression wastes CPU resources.  I guess I can just watch the folder to see how often it gets written to over time.

Comment: @Keltari *Sigh* you asked if it's *safe*, which it is. I already said it might be slower (because yes it uses more CPU). I also mentioned the kind of files it won't really help with. The fact that NTFS *works reliably on millions of PCs* is proof enough that NTFS compression is safe and reliable. What more do you need to know?